# Non- simplicity of $\text{Bir}(\mathbb{P}_\mathbb{R}^2)$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry

In this paper: https://perso.univ-rennes1.fr/serge.cantat/Articles/nsgc-acta-c.pdf the authors said that their article 'directly implied' that  $\text{Bir}(\mathbb{P}_\mathbb{R}^2)$ is not simple as well. How can we infer the non-simplicity of  $\text{Bir}(\mathbb{P}_\mathbb{R}^2)$ just from the fact that  $\text{Bir}(\mathbb{P}_\mathbb{C}^2)$ is not simple?

I am thinking of choosing a proper normal subgroup, say $N$, of $\text{Bir}(\mathbb{P}_\mathbb{C}^2)$ and intersecting it with $\text{Bir}(\mathbb{P}_\mathbb{R}^2)$. But there is no guarantee that $\text{Bir}(\mathbb{P}_\mathbb{R}^2)\cap N$ is non-trivial. How does one choose an $N$ s.t  $\text{Bir}(\mathbb{P}_\mathbb{R}^2)\cap N$ is nontrivial?

Comment: You're misquoting: they say (p3) "Our article directly implies...", not that "[their] result directly implies".

Comment: The logic has to be the other way: you have to start with a normal subgroup or $Bir(RP^2)$ and then prove that it is still normal in $Bir(CP^2)$ and hence trivial.

Comment: @ThiKu no this is not what they mean

Comment: @YCor I have edited my post. Sorry for that

Comment: @ThiKu I don't think this is what they are suggesting.

Comment: The point is that they show that for "sufficiently many" elements $g$ of $G_C=Bir(P^2_C)$, the normal subgroup generated by $g$ in $G_C$ is a proper subgroup, and even has a trivial intersection with $PGL_3(C)$. Their criterion makes it clear that $g$ can be chosen real, and hence the normal subgroup generated by $g$ in $G_R$ is proper, since it intersects trivially $PGL_3(R)$.

Comment: @YCor the fact that $N$ is proper iff it intersects trivially with $PGL_3(C)$ follows from Noether-Castelnuovo. Can we say that same for real case? Since Noether-Castelnuovo need not hold for the real plane Cremona group. (Correct me if im wrong.)

Comment: Note: "is a proper subgroup, and even has a trivial intersection with $PGL_3(C)$": more precisely it's a well-known consequence of an old result of M. Noether that these are equivalent (since $PGL_3(C)$ is simple and generates $Bir(P^2_C)$ as normal subgroup). Such a fact is not used in the real case. You just use that the intersection of the normal subgroup generated by $g$ in $Bir(P^2_R)$ is contained in the normal  subgroup generated by $g$ in $Bir(P^2_C)$, hence has trivial intersection with $PGL_3(C)$, hence has trivial intersection with $PGL_3(R)$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91498/discussion-between-thedilated-and-ycor).

Comment: @YCor Thank you for your response. I think i got it  Just a small doubt that I still have. How can we choose $g$ to be real? This is because $g$ is chosen in $\text{Bir}(X)$. How can we ensure the image of $g$ in $G_C$ is real as well?

Comment: "The image of $g$ in $G_C$" doesn't make sense to me. The Cantat-Lamy results looks like "for every fixed $m\ge 20$, every generic $g\in Bir(P^2)$ of degree $m$ is such that the normal subgroup generated by $g^{100}$ is a proper subgroup". (I reinvented constants.) Generic probably means, outside a countable union of subvarieties (inside those transformations of given degree).

Comment: ... So one should know that in the variety $X_m$ of birational self-transformations of $P^2$ of degree $m$, there are enough real points. I guess it's a rational variety over $\mathbf{Q}$, although I'm realizing that I'm not sure about this. Anyway, it's been proved by other authors that one can even find elements $g$ chosen in $Bir(P^2_Q)$.

Comment: @YCor because the automorphism $g:X\rightarrow X$ is chosen on the Kummer surface $X$. Since $X$ is rational to $CP^2$ then we can say the same for $G_C$. My question is how does the criterion laid put by the authors suggests that $g$ can be chosen to be real?

Comment: @YCor Do you have the references to those papers?

Comment: Check the Ann. Fourier paper of Anne Lonjou https://algebra.dmi.unibas.ch/lonjou/

Comment: @YCor thank you very much! Meanwhile if anyone else have any insightful comments do express your views here!

Answer (score 6):

(Since the question is answered in comments, I summarize it so as to provide an acceptable answer.)

The authors do not say that the non-simplicity result of $\mathrm{Bir}_{\mathbf{C}}(\mathbb{P}^2)$ implies that of$\mathrm{Bir}_{\mathbf{R}}(\mathbb{P}^2)$. They say that (the method of) the article implies that.

Namely, they show they show that for "many" $g\in \mathrm{Bir}_{\mathbf{C}}(\mathbb{P}^2)$, the normal subgroup generated by $g$ has trivial intersection with $\mathrm{PGL}_3(\mathbf{C})$. The way they define "many" applies to showing that $g$ can be chosen to belong to $\mathrm{Bir}_{\mathbf{R}}(\mathbb{P}^2)\smallsetminus\{1\}$. Hence the normal subgroup generated by such $g$ is a nontrivial proper subgroup of $\mathrm{Bir}_{\mathbf{R}}(\mathbb{P}^2)$.

Actually, in her Ann. Fourier paper, A. Lonjou provides an example of such $g$ inside $\mathrm{Bir}_{\mathbf{Q}}(\mathbb{P}^2)$, namely some power of the birational self-transformation $(x,y)\mapsto (y,y^2-x)$.

Answer (score 2):

Let me add more information to the answer of YCor (which is of course completely correct and accurate).

In the article of S. Cantat and S. Lamy, they take an element $g\in \mathrm{Bir}(\mathbb{P}^2)$ and give a criterion to say when the normal subgroup generated by a large power of $g$ is a strict subgroup of $g\in \mathrm{Bir}(\mathbb{P}^2)$. The proof works essentially over any algebraically closed field. Then, one has to give explicit elements that satisfy this property. This is done by them in the case where the field is algebraically closed, and can also be done for any field, as it was done by A. Lonjou in "Non simplicité du groupe de Cremona sur tout corps",
Annales de l'Institut Fourier, Vo 66, n°5, p.2021-2046, 2016.

The article is in french, freely available on the journal (open access free journal). The author also provides a translation on her webpage.

If you are interested in the field of real numbers, I would suggest you to keep a look at the article of S. Zimmermann "The abelianisation of the real Cremona group." Duke Math. J. vol. 167, no.2 (2018), 211--267. She shows that not only $\mathrm{Bir}_{\mathbb{R}}(\mathbb{P}^2)$ is not simple, but also that the abelianisation is a direct sum of $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ indexed by $\mathbb{R}$.

Also, for a version in higher dimension (which works over $\mathbb{C}$, $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{Q}$), see https://arxiv.org/abs/1901.04145